# New ASP.NET MVC 2 ViewMasterPage error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Im trying out ASP.NET MVC 2 and have immediately hit a problem with my first application.
When adding a View Master Page I get the following warning in VS 2008:
`\Views\Shared\ViewMasterPage.Master: ASP.NET runtime error: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`
Why is this? The System.Web.Mvc dll
is in the correct place and is referenced properly. I also have MVC 2 RC installed, 
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check your projectproperties for the targeted .NET framework (under "Compile"->"Advanced Compile Options") and check the web.config values for added assemblies (System.Web.Mvc in version 4.0.0.0)

When migrating our project to MVC2 the wizard did not update these values and I had issues with my views.

Maybe this is what is preventing you from using MVC2?